# Is there any algorithm to reduce around 40k characters into 2-3k characters?

Tags: java, android, string, algorithm, qr-code

I have been doing this project related QR code and I'm stuck at this stage where I have to generate a QR code containing information about the other 10K QR codes(batch). I thought of taking the first 4 characters in the hash-code of each QR code(in 10k batch) so that the generated QR code would be unique every time (even if a couple 100s QR code changes in the 10K batch).

**QR Code Data Capacity**

Numeric Only     Max. 7089 characters

Alphanumeric     Max. 4296 characters

Binary (8 Bits)  Max. 2953 characters

So are there any algorithms or techniques where I can convert a huge string into a small string that is unique every time??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To have a unique string, you can generate an GUID. It's maximum 68 bytes long depending on the format. It's not necessary to generate it from another string. You must have more requirements than just beeing to your string, than just being unique. Don't you need any useful information in the string ?

Comment: Any hashing algorithm can do that - but it's merely useless, since it's not reversible.

Comment: No there isn’t. However, do use your search engine to explore your options.

Comment: Try to make you code into MD 5 which is mostly to encrypt the data to unreadable this best its reduced the total string into 30 digits. Hope fully this will help you in your case.
The hash is always 128 bits. If you encode it as a hexdecimal string you can encode 4 bits per character, giving 32 characters. MD5 is not encryption. You cannot in general "decrypt" an MD5 hash to get the original string.

Comment: MD5 was broken 15 years ago. Do not use MD5. Use a hash algorithm which hasn't been broken.

Comment: I was thinking about using Adler-32 algorithm, by running a loop and grouping about 1k characters to generate unique 8-character code by this algorithm. Running this loop for around 40k characters gives an output of a string with 320 characters which can easily fit in a QR code. Any changes to the original 40k QR code's hash value can be easily reflected in this 320 character string. Is this the right approach?

Comment: @kaya3  For data compression (which this question seems to be about), not security, why does it matter that MD5 was "broken"?

Comment: @another-dave Security matters whether or not the question is about security. If there are some inputs which cause your code to give wrong answers, and it is known how to construct such inputs, then your code can be exploited to give wrong answers. If it's not known how to construct such inputs, then your code cannot practically be exploited in that way. There is no benefit to using a broken hashing algorithm, and it is trivial to use a non-broken one instead.

Comment: Do we have any evidence that it is possible for third parties to provide inputs to this code?  Since no details at all are given about what the program is, the answer is 'no".

Answer (score 0):

Please check here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/. They have loads of algorithms. You need to get the basic idea from here and customise as per your requirement. Hope this helps.